# unix grep command

Tags: unix, grep

I have a text file named "file1" containing the following data :

```
apple  
appLe  
app^e  
app\^e
```

Now the commands given are :

```
1.)grep app[\^lL]e file1  
2.)grep "app[\^lL]e" file1  
3.)grep "app[l\^L]e" file1  
4.)grep app[l\^L]e file1

output in 1st case : app^e

output in 2nd case :   
                     apple  
                     appLe  
                     app^e  

output in 3rd case :  
                     apple  
                     appLe  
                     app^e

output in 4th case :  
                     apple  
                     appLe  
                     app^e
```

why so..?
Please help..!

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: What are you expecting the output to be?

Comment: why the output is different when we give the pattern in double quotes("app[\^lL]e") and when the pattern is not given in double quotes..?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 1.)grep app[\^lL]e file1
```

The escape (\) is removed by the shell before grep sees it so this is equivalent to `app[^lL]e`. The bit in brackets matches anything not (from the ^, since it's the first character) L or l

```
 2.)grep "app[\^lL]e" file1
```

This time, the \ escapes the ^ so it matches ^ or L or l

```
 3.)grep "app[l\^L]e" file1
```

^ works to negate the set only if it is the first character, so this matches ^ or L or l

```
  4.)grep app[l\^L]e file1
```

The ^ is escaped, but since it's not the first it doesn't make any difference, so it matches ^ or L or l

Comment: thanks for a very nice and clear answer.. just a small doubt.. in the first case you said that "the escape is removed by the shell". what does that exactly mean.. can you please elaborate a bit more.  thanks!

Comment: \ is an escaping char for (standards) shells. Some chars have a special semantic, for instance `^` used in a range specification (at first place) is the complementary operator. So if you want the `^` char, not the operator you must escape it : `\^`. If you want to escape the escaping char itself : \\. Is this more clear ?

Answer (score 0):

In the first case `grep app[\^lL]e file1`, you do not quote the pattern on the command line, the shell takes care of its expansion. So the search pattern, effectively, becomes

```
app[^lL]e
```

and means: "app", then any symbol but "l" or "L", then "e". The only line that fits is

```
app^e
```

In other cases, `^` is either escaped and matched literally, or, in addition, it is in the middle of of the pattern.